# Why load incorrect manifest.mf when I execute jar

Tags: java, jar

```
InputStream manifestStream = ServiceController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")

Manifest manifest= new Manifest(manifestStream);
```

As above code in jar file, when I execute jar in command line on Mac, it reads other manifest file.

As far as I can test, this case just appear MAC and AWS service instance, it is not appear windows and linux server. that means this jar can reads expected manifest file in windows and linux server.

Can someone please take a look?

Executed command: `java -jar xxx.jar`

Jar file structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open file.jar by 7z or zip and look folder META-INF -> check  MANIFEST.MF file -> Check your Main-Class in this manifest file.
And you must remove *.RSA, *.MF in folder META-INF (only keep MANIFEST.MF file)

Comment: It is only one MANIFEST.MF file in our jar

Comment: Is this file true link: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and check your Main-Class in this manifest file?

Comment: yes, i am sure main class in this jar, and in manifest file, but there are two main class, one is 
`"mainClass:com.xxx.xxx.starter"`, 
another is 
`"Main-class:rg.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher"`